# Android 13 vibration is not working when "Vibration and haptics" is off

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-vibration, android-13

I target my application to Android 13 (API 33). My application has a vibration mode. When I put my application to vibrate mode it vibrates on actions instead of playing sound. The problem I'm facing is that in Android 13 when the "Vibration and haptics" is off from settings my application's vibration is also not working. Is there any that my application vibration always work even if the "Vibration and haptics" is off on the phone level.

And is their any way we could know in code that either "Vibration and haptics" is on or off?

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Not yet, I think Android team at Google have to check this :)

Comment: Any luck with that? It's been a year. It seems they need to give us a way in the api to access it.